# ESS ess-roxy-template-alist

Tags: r, emacs, roxygen2, ess

I would like to customize my roxygen2 template that is produced when I `C-c C-o C-o` on an R function.

If we take an example R function:

```
add <- function(x, y) {
    return(x + y)
}
```

and I have added this template in to my .emacs:

```
(setq ess-roxy-template-alist (list (cons "title" "")
                                    (cons "description" "")
                                    (cons "param" "")
                                    (cons "return" "")))
```

I get this:

```
##' @title 
##' 
##'
##' @param x 
##' @param y 
##' @return 
add <- function(x, y) {
    return(x + y)
}
```

I want this:

```
##' add 
##' 
##' @param x 
##' @param y 
##' @return 
add <- function(x, y) {
    return(x + y)
}
```

Any ideas how I can improve my .emacs so I don't have to always delete the word @title and manually type in the name of the function in the first line? I'm kind of lost in the ESS documentation. The only thing I found marginally useful was this: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2011-December/007342.html which doesn't solve it for me.

Comment: Why do you need to delete it in the first place? And having the title just be the function name isn't particularly great.

Comment: I always use the name of the function in the code the same as the name in the documentation. More details and descriptions go in their respective fields. Yes, I suppose I could leave the @title but the keystroke saver is really the detection of the function name to be placed in the roxygen documentation.

Comment: No idea, but I liked `sinew` package for automating the skeleton. https://www.r-bloggers.com/automating-roxygen2-package-documentation/